# Find the value of $n$ such that $(n-6)$ is divisible by $6$, $(n-7)$ is divisible by $7$ and $(n-8)$ is divisible by $8$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $(n-6)$ is divisible by $6$, $(n-7)$ is divisible by $7$ and $(n-8)$ is divisible by $8$, then what is the value of $n $?

Comment: obviously $k \times 6 \times  7 \times 8$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z} $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $n - 6$ is divisible by $6$, then so is $n$. Likewise for $7$ and $8$; that is, $n$ is divisible by $6$, $7$ and $8$. There are infinitely many such values; the smallest positive value is the least common multiple of $6$, $7$ and $8$.

Answer (score 2):

$n = 0$ works! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Also consider the least common multiple of $6, 7, 8$.

Answer (score 2):

$$n=6k+6=7l+7=8m+8$$
hence $n$ is a multiple of $6,7$ and $8$ hence $$n\in\operatorname{lcm}(6,7,8)\mathbb Z=168\mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 0):

$n\mid n-a \iff n\mid a,\,$ so hypotheses $\iff  6,7,8\mid n.\,$ But $\,\color{#c00}{6,7}\mid n \overset{(6,7) \,= \,1}\iff \color{#c00}{42}\mid n$

Thus $\ \color{#c00}{6,7},8\mid n\iff \color{#c00}{42},8\mid n\!\overset{\rm\ cancel\ 2}\iff  21,4\mid n/2 \overset{(21,4)\,=\,1}\iff 84\mid n/2 \iff 168\mid n $